# Getting an SQLSTATE[22007] error when associating role to a user for one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a one to many relationship between `users` and `roles`. I have three roles `administrator`, `employee` and `client`. I am unable to associate the user with a role.

Example:
When I am updating a user with a role `administrator`, I am successful in editing and saving the role to `employee` and `client`, but when I click save when the default role value remains unchanged i.e. `administrator`, it throws me an SQLSTATE[22007] error.

Please spare some time to have a look below.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[3]' for column `management`.`users`.`role_id` at row 1 (SQL: update `users` set `role_id` = [3], `users`.`updated_at` = 2021-01-29 05:08:12 where `id` = 3)
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/management/audience-management/user

[image: SQLSTATE ERROR]

- Database Structure

```
Users
----------
* id
* name
* email
* password
* role_id
* created_at

Roles
----------
* id
* name
* slug
* created_at
```

- User Model

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

- Role Model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

- User Controller

```
public $showUserUpdationModal = false;
public $role;
public User $user;

protected $rules = [
    'user.name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'user.email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
    'role' => 'required',
];

public function updateUser(User $user)
{
    $this->resetValidation();
        
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->role = $user->role()->pluck('id');
    $this->showUserUpdationModal = true;
}

public function storeUser()
{
    $this->validate();
    $this->validate([
        'user.email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$this->user->id,
    ]);
    $this->user->role()->associate($this->role);
    $this->user->save();
    $this->showUserUpdationModal = false;

    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('notify', $this->user->name.' Updated Successfully');
    $this->emit('sectionRefresh');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to assign the role_id value to an array instead of an integer.

Try saving the **role_id** as integer role id like:

```
$user->role_id = 1;
$user->save();
```

Instead of

```
$user->role_id = [1];
$user->save();
```

**EDIT**

Based on the code,

```
public function updateUser(User $user)
{
    $this->resetValidation();
        
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->role = $user->role_id; //This should world now
    $this->showUserUpdationModal = true;
}
```

Comment: But how can I do that, I don't understand, as I am getting the value from the roles table `@foreach ($roles as $role) <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option> @endforeach`, and then I straight away assign, how can I define it as an integer?

Comment: What value is coming from `$this->role` ?.

Comment: To mount the role in the modal component I used `$this->role = $user->role()->pluck('id');` whereas `$this-role` equals to value '1', '2', and '3' respectively. Please check the question again, as I have updated the User Controller code block.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks alot mate! Is there another way through which I can call the role relation and select id from the table? something like `$user->role()->select('id');`.

Comment: Yes. Use `$user->role->id`.